# name of value returned from PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm working on some code that talks to a PostgreSQL server for the first time (my experience is with SQL Server) and I need help figuring something out.

I've always tried to avoid "SELECT * ..." from code, but I can't figure out what the alternative is when calling a function.  (Unfortunately, all of the examples I've found do a "SELECT * ...")

Here's the function I'm trying to call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aSchema.aFunction(var1 text, var2 accountidentifier, ...)
  RETURNS int8
AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    retJobId    BIGINT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO aSchema.aTable (var1, var2, ...)
    VALUES (var1, var2, ...)
    RETURNING jobId INTO retJobId;

    PERFORM aSchema.anotherFunction(retJobId, ...);

    RETURN retJobId;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I've tried `SELECT retJobId FROM aSchema.aFunction(...)`, but I get `ERROR: column "retjobid" does not exist`.  Replacing "retJobId" with "*" works, but, like I said, I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: It would be *wrong* to avoid `SELECT *` on principal. There are use cases, where it's best avoided, but in other cases it's simply the right thing to do. Not in this case, though, as IMSoP's  answer already clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose between:

```
select aschema.afunction() as my_name;               -- like in IMSoP's answer
select my_name from aschema.afunction() as my_name;  -- with alias
select afunction from aschema.afunction();           -- with function name
```

If you add `aschema` to search path, you can omit schema identifier:

```
set search_path to public, aschema;
select afunction() as my_name;
select my_name from afunction() as my_name;
select afunction from afunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the function returns a scalar value (a single integer) you don't need to select FROM it at all, just select it as a single column, and give it a column alias so it's easily accessible in the calling code:

```
SELECT aSchema.aFunction(...) AS retJobId;
```

If this looks odd, consider it's just the same as selecting a mathematical expression, such as:

```
SELECT 6 * 9 AS answer;
```

In Oracle, you'd need a FROM clause, such as FROM dual, but Postgres doesn't require this.